# Which process owns the other side of a socket pair?

Tags: linux, pipe

```
ffmpeg -i bf25.flv pipe:17
```

I have this process write to pipe:17. How can I find out which process owns the other side of the socket pair? I am using linux kernel 2.6

Comment: Have a look at `lsof`, something like `sudo lsof -a | grep pipe:17`